# In need of some open address data, that i can match against a list of UK postcodes

Tags: data-request, address, location

I have a JSON document full of UK postcodes, and I need the list of addresses that are matched to these postcodes. Does anyone know where I can find this data?

Comment: Just to be clear, the "list of addresses" will be like 1 High Street, 3, High Street, 5 High Street, etc? (or Buck Palace, Clarence House, etc) I.E all buildings, for a given postcode? Be aware that some university halls of residence have a single postcode for hundreds of rooms/accommodations.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want @MawgsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: I guess that you are a coder? And looking for an API? This is a great question, and I don't have an answer  - yet.  It looks like you could scrape https://www.postoffice.co.uk/postcode-finder, but I would rather find you an official gratis API. Stay tuned ...

Comment: If this is a one-off exercise, then you might be able to use a trial membership on a for-pay site ...

Answer (score 0):

Adam, I love this question and would also like an answer.

Our aims may differ, though, if you want a one-of solution to handle your JSON file only (approx how many postcodes are in it?). I would like code a web site such that the user enters a post code & is given a drop-down list of associated addresses from which to choose. Let's see if we can't find a solution to both.

The accepted answer to [How do I match street addresses to UK postcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900221/how-do-i-match-street-addresses-to-uk-postcodes) says

> I believe you need the Royal Mail Postcode Address File. From that
> link:
>
> PAF is the only complete source of all known UK Postcodes.
>
> Services do exist to handle requests for this info, such that it may
> be cheaper to use such services for small numbers of requests
> (obviously you have issues as and when such services aren't available
> for whatever reasons).

When I follow up the PAF, I find it to be an expensive service (more than GBP 1k/year), ***but*** they do offer a [micro-business license](https://www.poweredbypaf.com/licence-our-products/licence-agreements/pricing/pricing-essentials-microbuisness/) which says

> If your organisation is a Microbusiness with less than 9 employees and
> turnover below £2 million per annum, you may be eligible to access
> free PAF Data for one year for the purpose of developing your
> addressing Solutions.
>
> If you wish to use our other complementary address data products, or
> continue to use PAF after your first year of use you will need to
> return the correct licence fees for the supply and use of each of our
> products. Fees are payable to Royal Mail in full every year.

So, it looks like you could use that license and would have a twelvemonth in which to manipulate your JSON file.

That won't help me, so I will continue to search futher & update this answer if I fidn other solutions

https://getaddress.io/ looked promising, but won't quite do it, I think.

I use the Open Street Map [nominatum API](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Lookup/) for other porpoises, but cant' quite see to achieve what we want with it:-( Great, free, API, though.

https://postcodes.io/ gives useful info from a post code, but, again, not what we want :-(

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The PAF would work for me, but i'm not sure they would give me the data since i'm not a business, just a student looking for data to use in my project. I have applied for the microbusiness license anyway, and ill see what i get back....

Comment: "`I'm not a business`" ... [on the internet nobody knows you're a dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog)  You can be a one-dog "trading as". You can also say, with truth, that if you make a pack of money with any app that you develop, then you will set up InternetDog, Ltd; after all, I am sure that you would :-)   Just curious, did they ask what you plan to do with the data? Please let us know how this turns out. Thanks